# Power BI - If columns name are different in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, report, powerquery, dashboard

In Power bi suppose i want to make dashboard where data is going to change every month ,but columns name are different soo how to deal with different columns name when data is going to change every month ?
(right now i am getting error as column names are different)

need solution how to deal with this type of data

Comment: You would need to dynamically target the said column in Powerquery and rename it. You'll want your data model to remain constant. Update your question with an example table in markdown format.

Answer (score 0):

One potential answer is to use powerquery / M to demote the column headers into first row, then remove first row.  All columns then become Column1, Column2, etc.

```
x = Table.RemoveFirstN(Table.DemoteHeaders(#"PriorStepNameHere),1)
```

[image]

or just directly specify the names of all the columns if you know how many there will be in advance

```
#"Rename"=Table.RenameColumns(#"PriorStepNameHere,List.Zip({Table.ColumnNames(#"PriorStepNameHere),{"Fixed1","Fixed2","Fixed3"}}))
```

[image]